# MatPlotLib imshow() muestra la imagen muy estrecha

Tags: python, matplotlib

Estoy intentando mostrar una matriz de tamaño: `(19189,252)` , sin embargo, al hacer `plt.show` me muestra una gráfica muy estrecha como la siguiente.

Aquí dejo el código:

```
def mostrarMatriz(input):
    target.astype(float)
    plt.figure(figsize=(20, 20))
    plt.imshow(input)
```

Si uso `plt.matshow(input)` me sale lo mismo.

La imagen que se me muestra es la siguiente: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es la primera vez que lo utilizo y no encuentro nada que me aclare mucho.
Gracias.

Comment: Hola, lo que me gustaría sería reescalar el eje x para poder ver mejor la imagen, sí.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para ajustar la relación de aspecto tienes el argumento `aspect`, el cual puede tomar los siguientes valores:

- **`"equal"`**: valor por defecto. Se asegura una relación de aspecto de 1, por lo que por defecto los píxeles se mostraran como cuadrados. Esto es lo que pasa en tu caso, dada la gran disparidad entre las dimensiones de tu array (:), obtienes una imagen en la que el ancho es apenas una línea:

  ```
  import numpy as np
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

  data = np.random.rand(19189, 88)
  plt.imshow(data) # plt.imshow(data, aspect="equal")
  plt.show()
  ```

  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
- Un **`float`**:

  ```
  import numpy as np
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

  data = np.random.rand(19189, 88)
  plt.imshow(data, aspect=0.01)
  plt.show()
  ```

  Valores menores de 0 harán el ancho proporcionalmente mayor al alto y valores mayores a 1 harán lo contrario.

  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
- **`"auto"`**: la relación d e aspecto se ajustará al tamaño de los ejes de forma automática y dinámica. Obviamente los pixeles se van a representar por lo general como rectángulos:

  ```
  import numpy as np
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

  data = np.random.rand(19189, 88)
  plt.imshow(data, aspect="auto")
  plt.show()
  ```

  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]